# How to use Dagger 2 to Inject ViewModel of same Fragments inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, dagger-2, androidx, android-mvvm

I am trying to add Dagger 2 to my project. I was able to inject ViewModels (AndroidX Architecture component) for my fragments.

I have a **ViewPager which has 2 instances of the same fragment** (Only a minor change for each tabs) and in each tab, I am observing a `LiveData` to get updated on data change (from API).

**The issue is that when the api response comes and updates the `LiveData`, the same data in the currently visible fragment is being sent to observers in all the tabs.** (I think this is probably because of the scope of the `ViewModel`).

This is how I am observing my data:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        activityViewModel.expenseList.observe(this, Observer {
            swipeToRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
            viewAdapter.setData(it)
        })
    ....
}
```

I am using this class for providing `ViewModel`s:

```
class ViewModelProviderFactory @Inject constructor(creators: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel?>?, Provider<ViewModel?>?>?) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private val creators: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel?>?, Provider<ViewModel?>?>? = creators
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator: Provider<out ViewModel?>? = creators!![modelClass]
        if (creator == null) { // if the viewmodel has not been created
// loop through the allowable keys (aka allowed classes with the @ViewModelKey)
            for (entry in creators.entries) { // if it's allowed, set the Provider<ViewModel>
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.key!!)) {
                    creator = entry.value
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        // if this is not one of the allowed keys, throw exception
        requireNotNull(creator) { "unknown model class $modelClass" }
        // return the Provider
        return try {
            creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG: String? = "ViewModelProviderFactor"
    }
}
```

I am binding my `ViewModel` like this:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityViewModelModule {
    @MainScope
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ActivityViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindActivityViewModel(viewModel: ActivityViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

I am using `@ContributesAndroidInjector` for my fragment like this:

```
@Module
abstract class MainFragmentBuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeActivityFragment(): ActivityFragment
}
```

And I am adding these modules to my `MainActivity` subcomponent like this:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {
...
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = [MainViewModelModule::class, ActivityViewModelModule::class,
            AuthModule::class, MainFragmentBuildersModule::class]
    )
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

Here is my `AppComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules =
    [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityBuilderModule::class,
        ViewModelFactoryModule::class,
        AppModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<SpenmoApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

I am extending `DaggerFragment` and injecting `ViewModelProviderFactory` like this:

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProviderFactory

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
....
activityViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(key, ActivityViewModel::class.java)
        activityViewModel.restartFetch(hasReceipt)
}
```

the `key` will be different for both the fragments.

How can I make sure that only the observer of the current fragment is getting updated.

EDIT 1 ->

I have added a sample project with the error. Seems like the issue is happening only when a custom scope is added. Please check out the sample project here: [Github link](https://github.com/jimmy-jose/BugRepro.git)

`master` branch has the app with the issue. If you refresh any tab (swipe to refresh) the updated value is getting reflected in both the tabs. This is only happening when I add a custom scope to it (`@MainScope`).

`working_fine` branch has the same app with no custom scope and its working fine.

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: I'm not getting why won't you use the approach from `working_fine` branch? Why do you need the scope?

Comment: @azizbekian I am currently using the working fine branch.. but I want to know, why would using scope break this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to recap the original question, here's it:

> I am currently using the working `fine_branch`, but I want to know, why would using scope break this.

As per my understanding your have an impression, that just because you are trying to obtain an instance of `ViewModel` using different keys, then you should be provided different instances of `ViewModel`:

```
// in first fragment
ViewModelProvider(...).get("true", PagerItemViewModel::class.java)

// in second fragment
ViewModelProvider(...).get("false", PagerItemViewModel::class.java)
```

The reality, is a bit different. If you put following log in fragment you'll see that those two fragments are using the exact same instance of `PagerItemViewModel`:

```
Log.i("vvv", "${if (oneOrTwo) "one:" else "two:"} viewModel hash is ${viewModel.hashCode()}")
```

Let's dive in and understand *why* this happens.

Internally `ViewModelProvider#get()` will try to obtain an instance of `PagerItemViewModel` from a `ViewModelStore` which is basically a map of `String` to `ViewModel`.

When `FirstFragment` asks for an instance of `PagerItemViewModel` the `map` is empty, hence `mFactory.create(modelClass)` is executed, which ends up in `ViewModelProviderFactory`. `creator.get()` ends up calling `DoubleCheck` with following code:

```
  public T get() {
    Object result = instance;
    if (result == UNINITIALIZED) { // 1
      synchronized (this) {
        result = instance;
        if (result == UNINITIALIZED) {
          result = provider.get();
          instance = reentrantCheck(instance, result); // 2
          /* Null out the reference to the provider. We are never going to need it again, so we
           * can make it eligible for GC. */
          provider = null;
        }
      }
    }
    return (T) result;
  }
```

The `instance` is now `null`, hence a new instance of `PagerItemViewModel` is created and is saved in `instance` (see // 2).

Now the exact same procedure happens for `SecondFragment`:

- fragment asks for an instance of `PagerItemViewModel`
- `map` now is *not* empty, but does *not* contain an instance of `PagerItemViewModel` with key `false`
- a new instance of `PagerItemViewModel` is initiated to be created via `mFactory.create(modelClass)`
- Inside `ViewModelProviderFactory` execution reaches `creator.get()` whose implementation is `DoubleCheck`

Now, the key moment. This `DoubleCheck` is **the same instance** of `DoubleCheck` that was used for creating `ViewModel` instance when `FirstFragment` asked for it. Why is it the same instance? Because you've applied a scope to the provider method.

The `if (result == UNINITIALIZED)` (// 1) is evaluating to false and the exact same instance of `ViewModel` is being returned to the caller - `SecondFragment`.

Now, both fragments are using the same instance of `ViewModel` hence it is perfectly fine that they are displaying the same data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense. But isn't there a way to fix this while using scope?

Comment: That was my question previously: why do you need to use scope? It's like you want to use a car when climbing a mountain and now you are saying _"ok, I get why I can't use a car, but how can I use a car to climb a mountain?"_ Your intentions are not obvious, please clarify.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong. My expectation was that using scope is a better approach. For eg. If there are 2 activities in my application(Login and Main), using 1 custom scope for login and 1 custom scope for main, will remove the unnecessary instances while one activity is active

Comment: > My expectation was that using scope is a better approach

It's not that one is better than the other. They are solving different problems, each have their use-case.

Comment: > will remove the unnecessary instances while one activity is active

Cannot see where from those "unnecessary instances" should be created. `ViewModel` is created with the lifecycle of activity/fragment and is destroyed as soon as it's hosting lifecycle is destroyed. You shouldn't manage the lifecycle/creation-destroying of ViewModel on your own, that's what architecture components are doing for you as a client of that API.

Comment: Scopes are used to ensure _"singletonnes"_ within the component. In your problem you do **not** want the `ViewModel` to be the same instance for those fragments. You want those instances to be different, hence scope is not applicable. Also, let's consider the opposite case when you want these two fragments to use the same instance of `ViewModel`: in that case you'd better ask for in instance of `ViewModel` using the activity, **not** the fragment: `ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity(), viewModelFactory)`. In this case those two fragments will use same `ViewModel`, hence no need for scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Both the fragments receive the update from livedata because viewpager keeps both the fragments in resumed state. 
Since you require the update only on the current fragment visible in the viewpager, the context of the **current** fragment is defined by the host activity, the activity should explicitly direct updates to the desired fragment.

You need to maintain a map of Fragment to LiveData containing entries for all the fragments(make sure to have an identifier that can differentiate two fragment instances of the same fragment) added to viewpager.

Now the activity will have a MediatorLiveData observing the original livedata observed by the fragments directly. Whenever the original livedata posts an update, it will be delivered to mediatorLivedata and the mediatorlivedata in turen will only post the value to livedata of the current selected fragment. This livedata will be retrieved from the map above.

Code impl would look like -

```
class Activity {
    val mapOfFragmentToLiveData<FragmentId, MutableLiveData> = mutableMapOf<>()

    val mediatorLiveData : MediatorLiveData<OriginalData> = object : MediatorLiveData() {
        override fun onChanged(newData : OriginalData) {
           // here get the livedata observed by the  currently selected fragment
           val currentSelectedFragmentLiveData = mapOfFragmentToLiveData.get(viewpager.getSelectedItem())
          // now post the update on this livedata
           currentSelectedFragmentLiveData.value = newData
        }
    }

  fun getOriginalLiveData(fragment : YourFragment) : LiveData<OriginalData> {
     return mapOfFragmentToLiveData.get(fragment) ?: MutableLiveData<OriginalData>().run {
       mapOfFragmentToLiveData.put(fragment, this)
  }
} 

class YourFragment {
    override fun onActivityCreated(bundle : Bundle){
       //get activity and request a livedata 
       getActivity().getOriginalLiveData(this).observe(this, Observer { _newData ->
           // observe here 
})
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using `FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)` so how is viewpager keeping both fragments in resumed state? This was not happening before I added dagger 2 to the project.

Comment: I will try and add a sample project with the said behavior

Comment: Hey I have added a sample project. Can you please check it. I will also add a bounty for this.(Sorry for the delay)

Comment: @hushed_voice Sure will get back to you.